# QSqlQuery size() always returns -1

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite, qsqlquery

```cpp
QSqlQuery query;
QString queryText("SELECT * FROM section");
query.exec(queryText);
qDebug() << query.size(); //always -1
while (query.next()) qDebug() << query.value(0).toString(); //got 16 records
```

Method `size()` always returns -1.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`query.size()` is not supported with SQLite. But you can get the number of rows with a workaround.

`QSqlQuery::last ()` retrieves the last record in the result, if available, and positions the query on the retrieved record. After calling `last()` you can retrieve the index of the last record and position the query before the first record using `first()` and `previous()`:

```cpp
int numberOfRows = 0;
if(qry.last())
{
    numberOfRows =  qry.at() + 1;
    qry.first();
    qry.previous(); 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From [QSqlQuery::size](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsqlquery.html#size):

> Returns the size of the result (number of rows returned), or -1 if the
> size cannot be determined or if the database does not support
> reporting information about query sizes. Note that for non-SELECT
> statements (isSelect() returns false), size() will return -1. If the
> query is not active (isActive() returns false), -1 is returned.
>
> To determine the number of rows affected by a non-SELECT statement,
> use numRowsAffected().

Your query `isSelect` and active, but SQLite is one of the databases for which the size of the query is not directly available.

To prove this, call this for example:

```cpp
qDebug() <<db.driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::QuerySize);
```

It returns `false`.

Answer (score 3):

For myself I use this function

```
int sqlSize(QSqlQuery query)
{
    int initialPos = query.at();
    // Very strange but for no records .at() returns -2
    int pos = 0;
    if (query.last())
        pos = query.at() + 1;
    else
        pos = 0;
    // Important to restore initial pos
    query.seek(initialPos);
    return pos;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I get the same problem when using qsqlite in qt5. **query.size** always return -1,  so i use query.first() instead.

```
QString username = ui->usernameInput->text();
QString password = ui->passwordInput->text();
QString command = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = '" + username + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
QSqlQuery query;
if (query.exec(command)) {
    qDebug() << query.size(); // the size will always -1 when using QSqlite
    if (query.first()) { // so i use query.first() to check if there has any result
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Login success.", "You have successfully logged in!");
    } else {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "Login failed.", "Please Check the username and password");
    }
}
```