# Qt SQL query.exec Always Returning True

Tags: c++, sql, qt, sqlite

Im creating a login system in qt using a database but when I run the query in qt it is always returning true, even when that item is false.

The sql database connection code is below

```
QSqlDatabase login = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
login.setDatabaseName("/Users/Daniel/Dropbox/Stock_Control.sqlite");
if(!login.open())
    ui->label->setText("Unable To Connect To Database");
```

The SQL query code is below

```
static Home *home = new Home;
QSqlQuery query;
QString Username = ui->Username_lineEdit->text();
QString Password = ui->Password_lineEdit->text();
if(query.exec("SELECT * FROM Program_account WHERE Login = '"+ Username +"' AND Password = '"+ Password +"' "))
{
    tries = 0;
    home->show();
    close();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Don't forget about sql injection.. username and password is a trivial case.

Answer (score 1):

`QSqlQuery::exec()` returns `true` when the query is executed successfully, even if the query is empty. Use `QSqlQuery::size()` function to check if the query is empty or not.

**UPDATE**

Since `QSqlQuery::size()` always returns -1 for sqlite, you can use `QSqlQuery::first()` instead.

You can do something like:

```
if(!query.exec("SELECT Login FROM Program_account WHERE Login = '"+ Username +"' AND Password = '"+ Password +"' "))
{
    // something is terribly wrong
}
else if(!query.first())
{
    // incorrect username or password
}
else
{
    tries = 0;
    home->show();
    close();
}
```

Comment: It is wrong,because size() always returns -1 for SQLite,because SQLite does not support this. See answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26495049/qsqlquery-size-always-returns-1

Comment: @Chernobyl, thank you for pointing this out, I fixed the answer. It should now work for sqlite as well